# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application-(in Edit Text)

Tags: android, exception, android-edittext

I got this Error and can't catch Exception. I really confused why I can't catch , Before Works.

Here I've 2 EditText I want to check if it's empty do somework. I used other methods to check is Empty but doesn't work and Exit from app.

Code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
        ad.setTitle("خطا");

        sp=sp=getSharedPreferences("sp", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

        bsobh=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Bsobh);
        bzohr=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Bzohr);
        basr=(Button) findViewById(R.id.basr);
        bmaqrib=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bmaqrib);
        besha=(Button) findViewById(R.id.besha);
        brooze=(Button) findViewById(R.id.brooze);
        ok=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);

        etnamaz=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ettedaderoozenamaz);
        etrooze=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ettedadroozerooze);



    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    try{

                    int temp=Integer.parseInt(etnamaz.getText().toString());
                    sobh=temp;
                    zohr=temp;
                    asr=temp;
                    maqrib=temp;
                    esha=temp;

                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        ad.setMessage("لطفا تعداد روزهایی که نمازتان قضا شده است را وارد کتید");
                        ad.show();

                }

                    try{
                rooze=Integer.parseInt(etrooze.getText().toString());
                }
                    catch(Exception e){
                    ad.setMessage("لطفا تعداد روزهایی که روزه تان قضا شده است را وارد کتید");
                    ad.show();
                }

                inserted=true;
                update();


            }
        }); 
}
```

Comment: post where you initialized your edittext

Comment: works when edittext is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
works when edittext is not empty
```

**problem:**

```
int temp=Integer.parseInt(etnamaz.getText().toString());
```

you cant `parse a string to int` when it is **empty** you will likely to get `numberMismatchException`.

**solution:**

check it first if the `etnamaz` or `etrooze` has some values before parsing it to int.

**sample:**

```
if(etnamaz.getText().length() != 0)
//if it has some values
else
//if it doesnt have value
```

**EDIT:**

instead of getting the whole application context, you need to get the activity context using the `this`

```
ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think we cant do this. I use

```
Toast t =Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please ente quantity or enter 0 if none", 5000);
t.show();
```

Instead of

```
 ad.setMessage("لطفا تعداد روزهایی که روزه تان قضا شده است را وارد کتید");
                ad.show();
```

and Works Correctly.